# Using JREPL with Special Characters

Tags: replace, cmd, special-characters, str-replace, jrepl

I am trying to replace the below

```
UninstallPassword="1"
```

with

```
UninstallPassword="0"
```

I am using JREPL.bat and so far can only replace content that does not have special characters.
Reading the documentation under /x says I must use /q but I am not sure how to format the line of code for it. I have tried:

`jrepl.bat "\qUninstallPassword="1"" "\qUninstallPassword="0"" /f "%userprofile%\pol.txt" /o -`

and

`jrepl.bat "UninstallPassword\q=\q"1\q"" "UninstallPassword\q=\q"0\q"" /f "%userprofile%\pol.txt" /o -`

but both make no change to the text.

Any help appreciated, and alternatively if Windows CMD has a builtin function to acheive the same as JREPL then that would be ideal and keep the script as a standalone.

Comment: if there were a built-in function in `cmd`, Dave wouldn't have written `jrepl.bat` in the first place. You can write a script (reading and processing the file line by line - there are several examples on SO), but `jrepl` makes it easier, safer and faster (when you know how to use it's numerous features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use `\q`, you have to enable it with `/XSEQ`. `\q` is then used as a placeholder for `"`, so replace each `"` with `\q` within the patterns. Don't replace the outer quotes surrounding the patterns:

```
jrepl.bat "UninstallPassword=\q1\q" "UninstallPassword=\q0\q" /XSEQ /f "%userprofile%\pol.txt" /o -
```

Comment: Wow, I spent the better part of my afternoon trying to get this right and it was as simple as that to get it working. Thank you very much Stephen